# Microsoft Teams call notifications are hidden if any app is in full screen mode

Tags: macos, microsoft-teams

I'm using the native macOS app of Microsoft Teams. Whenever an app is presented in full screen mode, for example Safari or even Teams itself, visual incoming call notifications are not displayed. The ringtone is audible.

If I leave full screen mode or switch back to the desktop space, the notification and buttons to accept the call are suddenly visible in the top right corner of the screen.

I have given Teams permission to take control of and record the screen, as well as access to camera and audio.

I couldn't find any settings in Teams related to call notifications. Is there any way to still see and interact with incoming calls while using an app in full screen mode?

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue because MS Teams has its own implementation of notifications, which aren't displayed in fullscreen apps (and other use cases).

A lot of people have complained about this and requested the native macOS notifications to be implemented.
You can find the [feature request/thread here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/16941685-use-built-in-notifications-for-macos).
This has been posted a while ago and they started working on it since April 2018, but no actual progress update has been given. The last update was in February 2020 saying they're working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a version of 1.5.00.17261.
[image]